# Ajax Json data - How to access the returned Json data

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

When I click on the `listproduct` (which is an invoice no) I will open up a collapsible table listing the products matching the invoice no.

My View File:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".listproduct").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        alert(value);
        $.post('<?=site_url("purchase_controller/getproductlist"); ?>', {data:value},function (result) {
            alert(result[1][1]["invoiceno"]);

            for(i=1;i<result["count"];i++){ //loop trough elements
                $('#products tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + result[i]['invoiceno'] + '</td><td>' + result[i]['productname'] + '</td><td>' +   result[i]['price'] + '</td></tr>');
            }
        });

        $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
    });
});
</script>

<table id="products">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >Invoice No</td>
            <td>productname</td>
            <td> quantity</td>
            <td> price</td>
            <td> amount</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Controller File:

```
public function getproductlist(){
    // check if is an ajax request
    // if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    // echo "entered";

    // checks if the variable data exists on the posted data
    if($this->input->post('data')){
        //query in your model you should verify if the data passed is legit before querying
        $query = $this->purchasemodel->getproductlists($this->input->post('data'));
        $data['records'] = $query['records'];
        $data['count'] = $query['count']; 
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));

        return $data;
    }
    // }
}
```

My output when debugged - response for ajax:

```
{ "records": [
    {"id":"39","invoiceno":"55","price":"30000","quantity":"2", "amount":"60000","productname":"Tab"},
    {"id":"41","invoiceno":"55", "price":"200","quantity":"4","amount":"800","prod    uctname":"zdsfS"}
  ],
  "count":2
}
```

But this is  the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: result[1] is undefined

alert(result[1][1]["invoiceno"]);
```

Comment: That's because it's `undefined`. `alert(result.records[0].invoiceno);`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `parseJSON()` function will parse the JSON string.

```
var resultObj = $.parseJSON( result );
alert(resultObj.records[1].invoiceno);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

You need parse your json and then you can access invoice number using object see my code snippet. See more details for json [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '{"records": [{"id":"39","invoiceno":"55","price":"30000","quantity":"2","amount":"60000","productname":"Tab"},{"id":"41","invoiceno":"55","price":"200","quantity":"4","amount":"800","prod    uctname":"zdsfS"}],"count":2}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.records[1]['invoiceno'] + "<br>";

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
alert(result['records'][1]["invoiceno"]);
```

This is working ! i JUST GOT IT :)